# Site won't scroll down in chrome

Tags: html, css

Isn't scrolling down for some reason at all, it's working completely fine on internet explorer and Mozila, but on google chrome it's refusing to scroll down at all. Please help me! I don't know what to do.

Filip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `return false` from `jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.js` file, It prevent the scrolling in chrome browser....

```
$('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    wheel = true;
    if (delta < 0) // down
        top = (top+viewport) >= doc.height() ? top : top+=step;
    else // up
        top = top <= 0 ? 0 : top-=step;

    body.stop().animate({scrollTop: top}, speed, self.ease, function () {
        wheel = false;
    });
    // return false;   // remove this
});
```